# Need SSRS Select All parameter to output "All"

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, parameters

I have a parameter in SSRS that populates all the states.  There is a text box that displays the selected text using State(s): " & Join(Parameters!state.Value,",").

The issue is that if a user chooses the Select All option the text box will display all 50 states, which looks kind of messy.  I was hoping for the text box to just read "State(s): All" in that instance.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: =IIF(COUNTROWS("dataset").Equals(Parameters!parameter.Count),"it is equal","this is not equal")

Comment: That worked great!  Thanks!

Comment: Snowlock is correct but to clarify, the dataset is obviously the "dataset" that provides values to your parameter.